# Super of certain class in Objective C

Tags: objective-c, class, superclass, super

How to send message to certain superclass?
For example:

```
@interface A: NSObject;

@interface B: A;

@interface C: B;

@implementation C

- (id)init {
  [super init];
}
```

, where "super" is class A, but not B

Comment: Why would you want to do this?  It violates a pretty fundamental aspect of object-oriented inheritance.

Comment: Why not? I want to override method of super-superclass, but all other methods - from superclass. And i could do it in c++.

Comment: i have big tree of classes, and i want to reduce implementation of one method, but don't touch implementation of this method in  super-super class.

Comment: Maybe you can define in B a method to bypass B and call A's method. Of course, this can be annoying if you have a lot of classes to bypass...

Comment: yes, its actually solution, but i can't modify code in classes A and B. i need to do it in C class files.

Comment: Oh yes, i can do it with category. Maybe it is solution.

Comment: If you actually need to do this, somebody's code is badly broken.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could always get the IMP for a selector of any class, and call it manually.

```
@implementation C
- (id)init
{
    IMP a_init = [A instanceMethodForSelector:_cmd];
    return a_init(self, _cmd);
}
@end
```

You can also one-line it, `return [A instanceMethodForSelector:_cmd](self, _cmd);`

For the record, `_cmd` is provided to you by Objective-C, and is the `SEL` of the current method.